# How to create mock for hash in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm Japanese.Excuse me in ugly English.

I want to create hash mock.

so, I try this code,

but error occured

```
To allow expectations on `nil` and suppress this message, set `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` to `true`. To disallow expectations on `nil`, set `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.allow_message_expectations_on_nil` to `false`.
```

Is there any other way of writing?
Please teach me.

```rb
AppointmentRank.new(
            id: appointment.id,
            name: @rank[appointment.rank_id]
          )
```

`@rank` is hash.

rspec

```rb
let(:rank){{ 1 => 'S', 2 => 'A', 3 => 'B' }}
let(:rank_id){2}

allow(@rank).to receive(:[]).with(rank_id).and_return('A')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `let` doesn't create *instance variables*.

your `let` lines create *methods* named `rank` and `rank_id` that are available in your tests:

```
RSpec.describe "let behavior" do
  let(:rank){{ 1 => 'S', 2 => 'A', 3 => 'B' }}
  let(:rank_id){2}

  it "defines a method not an instance variable" do
    expect(@rank).to be_nil
    expect(rank).to be_a Hash
  end
end
```

So in other words, don't use `@rank` or `@rank_id` in your tests unless you define them. Use `rank` and `rank_id` instead

Instance variables in Ruby are nil if they are not declared. That's why it doesn't raise an error to call `@rank`, even though it's actually undefined.